# Install B2B Customer module (deprecated). In VirtoCommerce

Tags: virtocommerce

B2B Custumer module give migration error after install and restart module.
My Virtocommerce platform version is 2.13.35 community.

I hope some can help you to solve this error.

Thanks In Advance...

Answer (score 1):

As you said, this module is obsolete and is no longer supported.
All the necessary b2b functionality is built into other modules in the new version platform.